# Evaluating an integral $\int_{-2}^12(x-4)^2dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$\int_{-2}^12(x-4)^2dx$ is the one I'm doing. I got 126 as an answer but am being told it's not right. Spent an hour messing with it, then put in into an online calculator that told me I was right, so I need held figuring out what's going on with this one. [This is what I to get that.](http://i949.photobucket.com/albums/ad332/Fractur65/DSCN0312.jpg)

Comment: Please show your working

Comment: What antiderivative did you find for $2(x-4)^2$?

Comment: I used the u substitution thing and then did 2/3 u^3 so (2/3)(x-4)^3

Comment: $126$ is the correct answer

Comment: *Who told you that this isn't right?!?*

Comment: The automatic online quiz thing for my math class. After looking over all my notes i was sure I was doing it right, but wanted to confirm it was the quiz's issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [this tinyurl link to W|A](http://tinyurl.com/pjt4go4), your solution is correct.

And I can verify that the work you uploaded is also correct. You will want to be careful to change the limits of integration when using u-substitution though. In this case, $u = x - 4$ gives that the lower limit ($x = -2)$ corresponds to $u = -6$. The upper limit for $u$ is $-3$.

Answer (score 2):

You're right.
\begin{equation} \int_{-2}^{1} (2x^2 - 16x + 32)dx \end{equation}
when you integrate, it becomes
\begin{equation}= (\frac{2}{3} x^3 - 8x^2 + 32x)  \end{equation} 
so:
\begin{equation} = \Big[ \frac{2}{3} (1)^3 - 8(1)^2 + 32(1) \Big] - \Big[ \frac{2}{3} (-2)^3 - 8(-2)^2 + 32(-2) \Big] \end{equation}
\begin{equation} = 126 \end{equation}